# Proper analysis of completely crossed design with subjects and items as random effects (brms)

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian, brms, crossed-random-effects

I have the following study design:

- **stimuli**: 240 pictures:

  - 6 pictures of 40 students each
  - (each student fixated one of six points and during each fixation one picture was taken)
  - each stimulus was rated 4 times by each subject
- **independent variable**: gaze direction (point 2 to 6 in degrees of visual angle, only positive values; 0° was omitted, see below)
- **dependent variable**: ratio (`gdr`; only positive values) of perceived (`pgd`) to ground truth gaze direction (`gtgd`, obviously not for 0°)

**Overall goal**: examine the relationship between some characteristics of the photographed students eyes (2 measures per student, constant across all images of each student) and the ratios of perceived to ground truth gaze direction.

**Subgoals**:

1. get the `gdr`for each `gtgd` as well as the variation due to subjects and variation due to photographed students
2. check, whether any of the pairwise differences between the `gdr`s (say, `gdr` for `gtgd = 2.2°` and `gdr` for `gtgd = 4.4°`, ...) are significant different from 0 (supporting the decision *not* to regress `pdg` on `gtgd` as has been done before, the latter not without lots of criticism).

Following [Baayen et al. (2008)](https://psycnet.apa.org/doi/10.1016/j.jml.2007.12.005) I tried to set this up as mixed model using brms.

**My approach**:
I used cell mean parametrization to directly model the population level estimates of each `gdr`. `gtgd_fct` is just the dv `gtgd` as factor with levels 2.2, 4.4, 6.6, 8.8, 13.3.

```
library(brms)

init_func <- function(chain_id = 1){
  list(
    sigma = 1
  )
}

init_list <- list(
  init_func(chain_id = 1),
  init_func(chain_id = 2),
  init_func(chain_id = 3),
  init_func(chain_id = 4)
)

full_model <- brm(gdr ~ 0 + gtgd_fct + (0 + gtgd_fct | lID) + (0 + gtgd_fct | sID),
            data = df_bayes,
            prior = c(set_prior("lkj(0.9)", class = "cor"),
                    set_prior("student_t(3, 1, 1.5", class = "sigma", lb = 0),
                      set_prior("normal(1, 1)", class = "sd", lb = 0)),
            iter = 40000,
            warmup = 2000,
            chains = 4,
            cores = 8,
            init = init_list,
            control = control,
            sample_prior = TRUE,
            save_pars = save_pars(all = TRUE))
```

The model fits fine and performs better than the same model without correlation between factor levels (`brm(gdr ~ 0 + gtgd_fct + (0 + gtgd_fct || lID) + (0 + gtgd_fct || sID)`) or models without by-student or by-subject random effects in terms of loo or waic.

My problems:

1. I think, since `gdr` is continuous with lower bound = 0, I should use a different distribution family (ExGaussian? Weibull?)
2. After fitting the model, how do I perform comparisons on the differences between the different factor levels?
3. How to obtain the estimates needed for the overall goal (that is, student/photograph x `gtgd` specific `gdr` estimates to be used as dv in a multivariate regression? Are these just the population level estimates + the student specific random effects?

Any help or hint to a solution is much aprreciated.

Comment: Why do you define the outcome variable Y as a ratio -- with this definition, Y is undefined for gtgd = 0 so straight away you throw away a portion of the data. (And I assume gtgd = 0 means "straight ahead" which would be something like a baseline / calibration for the gaze fixation task?) What about letting Y = pgd. Or (Y = pgd - gtgd though I think modeling pgd would be better.)